# Pass the view that manages something to the second view - Backbone

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have two views, one for rendering google maps and another to render list of events that contain's latitude and longitude to render markers on the view that contains google maps. When I try to pass the view that manages the map to the initialize method of the second view and save an instance reference, display in console the following error:

[image]

Here's my code

app.js

```
var ev = new Application();

ev.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "evento/:id" : "evento"
    }, 

    home: function(){
        var mapView = new ev.views.Home();
        $('#home').html(mapView.el);
        $('#rightcolumn').html(new ev.views.Home_Eventos(mapView).el);
    },

    evento: function(id){
        $('#rightcolumn').html(new ev.views.Evento(id).el);

    }
});

$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // Load HTML templates for the app
    ev.templateLoader.load(['shell', 'home', 'home_list_eventos', 'evento'], function () {
        ev.shell = new ev.views.Shell({el: "#shell"});
        ev.router = new ev.Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
});
```

home.js

```
ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
    map: 'null',
    initialize: function(){
        this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home'));
        this.render();
    },

    initMap: function(){

        var that = this;
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos;
                pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: that.map,
                    position: pos
                });

                that.map.setCenter(pos);
            });
        }

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
        };
        that.map = new google.maps.Map(that.$el.find('#map_canvas')[0],mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = that.map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(that.map, "resize");
            that.map.setCenter(center); 
        });
    },

    render: function(){

                this.$el.html(this.template());
                this.initMap();
                return this;    
    }
});
```

home_events.js

```
ev.views.Home_Eventos = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(mapView){
        this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home_list_eventos'));
        this.mapView = mapView;
        console.log(this.mapView.map);
        this.render();
        console.log("sou inicializado");
    },

    render: function(){

        var that = this;
        var imagens = new ev.models.ImagemCollection();
        imagens.fetch({
            success: function(){
                that.$el.html(that.template({imagens: imagens.models}));


                var marcadores = imagens.models;
                setTimeout(function() {
                _.each(marcadores, function(marcador){
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marcador.get('latitude'),marcador.get('longitude'));
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                    });

                });
                    }, 6000);

                return that;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Templates of document:
shell.html:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    ...
</nav>

<div class="wrapper-home" id="home">

</div><!--/.fluid-container-->
```

home.html:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5 coluna-input">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pesquisar">Pesquise</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pesquisar" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="quando">Quando</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quando" placeholder="Quando">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 coluna-input">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pac-input">Onde</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pac-input" placeholder="Onde">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="genero">Género</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genero" placeholder="Genero">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 coluna-input">
            <button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary botao">Pesquisar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 coluna-input">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger botao">Mais Filtros</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr class="linha"/>

    <div class="row" id="lista">
        <div class="table">
            <tbody>
                <% _.each(imagens, function(imagem){  %>
                <tr>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 coluna-input">
                        <img src="<%= imagem.get('imagem') %>" class="img-responsive  back" alt="Responsive image">
                        <a href='#evento/<%= imagem.get('id') %>' class="btn btn-primary">Ver Mais</a>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you pass the `mapView` into `Home_Eventos` but never use it in that view? Could you also show your HTML document to get a sense for the element hierarchy on your site?

Comment: I never use `mapView` in `Home_Eventos` because I receive a null value. I'll show the html document

Comment: I just notice another potential problem. You initialize `new ev.views.Home_Eventos(mapView)` as a parameter to `$.html()`, which is fine except that the `render` function in that view is `async` because of the fetch in it. So the `el`it returns should be an empty `<div>` since the `success` callback doesn't return until after the `initialize` is complete

Comment: I found the error. I can not pass the `mapView` into `ev.views.Home_Eventos` because as you said like you said, when the changing of the home view is initialized would do the append the $el `shell` instead of `rightcolumn`. As I just need variable that contains the map just spent this `mapView.map`

Comment: Do you mind if I write that up as the answer?

Comment: No, I don't mind. You can write the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `new ev.views.Home_Eventos(mapView)` as a parameter to `$.html()`, which is fine except that the render function in that view is 'async' because of the fetch in it. So the `el` it returns should be an empty `<div>` since the success callback doesn't return until after the `initialize` is complete.